# Download vagrant boxes via tutorial syntax

Tags: vagrant

About to start tinkering with vagrant, looking at the [second page of the tutorial](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/boxes.html)

```
vagrant box add hashicorp/precise64
```

When I run this command however, I get

> This command was not invoked properly. The help for this command is
>   available below.
>
> Usage: vagrant box add   [--provider provider] [-h]

I can see it takes a name before the URL, so I tried

```
vagrant box add ubuntu/trusty64 https://atlas.hashicorp.com/ubuntu/boxes/trusty64
```

but I get another error

> bsdtar: Error opening archive: Unrecognized archive format

I want to download `ubuntu/trusty64` specifically. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using old version of Vagrant with newest documentation. You either need to update your Vagrant or [read old docs](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/blob/v1.4.3/website/docs/source/v2/boxes.html.md).

Boxes system was [revamped in 1.5](http://www.vagrantup.com/blog/feature-preview-vagrant-1-5-boxes-2-0.html) so your Vagrant is older than 1.5

Answer (score 0):

I used a different site to get the boxes. The url needs to have a `.box` file

```
https://oss-binaries.phusionpassenger.com/vagrant/boxes/latest/ubuntu-14.04-amd64-vbox.box
```